# Specific Header with Action Buttons

Tags: android, header

currently many apps have the same header, with diffrent font, gradiant background but on the right mostly the same buttons like search, add ...

Some of popular examples would be WhatsApp, Google Docs, Facebook.

How can I implement such an header in my app, and how does this "specific header" is called?

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just keep that header background set to all the pages in xml and then you can put any buttons on that header.